# How to only look at the last 10 minutes of a log and grep for statement

Tags: linux, weblogic

I'm looking for a way to only look through the last 10 mins of a WebLogic log file that has line formatting like this.

```
####<Sep 21, 2018 1:56:20 PM EDT> <Notice> <Stdout>
```

I want to grep for a specific string and if it fails wait 60 seconds and try again. This would be for RHEL 7, and I'm open to using sed, awk, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you're using RHEL 7 `WebLogic` is probably using systemd now.  Which means you can take advantage of `journalctl` and the `--since` option.

From this article https://www.qualogy.com/techblog/oracle/introducing-weblogic-to-systemd# it looks like you'll use either `wls_nodemanager` or `wls_adminserver` or both.  To view both use:

`journalctl -u wls_nodemanager -u wls_adminserver --since "10min ago"`

Answer (score -1):

If you were to relax the requirement of the last 10 minutes, and use GNU coreutils and grep, this is pretty easy:

`tail -f -s 60 -n +0 file.txt  | grep  -m 1 pattern`

Tail the entire file by starting on line zero (`-n +0`), poll it every `-s` seconds, and grep stops after `-m` matches.

For a one-off interactive search, I wouldn't bother date parsing, and would at first manually change the starting line with the  `tail -n`.  Date parsing could be by writing a script in your favorite script language with a decent module for that (Python, Perl).

Finally, if you want a search engine for your logs, look to implment event management systems like Graylog, ELK, Splunk, Log Insight, LogRhythm etc.